# Why no cmd_vel topic when running Turtlebot simulation on ROS + Gazebo?

Tags: ros, simulation, gazebo, turtlebot2

I have been having a very difficult time trying to understand why my system does not have the cmd_vel topic.  I am trying to get a ROS system running with Gazebo so that I can work through tutorials and learn ROS.  I started with the ROS Development Studio (online) and it was great!  But sooner or later one must be able to get ROS going on a local system.  So I built a Ubuntu system and installed ROS + Gazebo, then installed Turtlebot including the simulator.  It all works!  I can launch a Turtlebot simulation then launch the Turtlebot_teleop package and I am able to move the robot around.
But when I list the running topics cmd_vel is not one of them.  These are the list of topics grep'd on "cmd":

```
scott@Ubvm:~/catkin_ws/devel$ rostopic list | grep cmd
/cmd_vel_mux/active
/cmd_vel_mux/input/navi
/cmd_vel_mux/input/safety_controller
/cmd_vel_mux/input/switch
/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop
/cmd_vel_mux/parameter_descriptions
/cmd_vel_mux/parameter_updates
```

No /cmd_vel!  So I can't work through tutorials to drive the robot around.  Besides, I just don't understand why it is not there but teleop works.

Could someone tell me why I do not see the cmd_vel topic?

**System info:**

Ubuntu 16.04

ROS Kinetic

Gazebo 7 (not sure exactly which version but it launches and runs)

Installed Turtlebot based on Indigo install but replaced with kinetic.

```
sudo apt-get install 
ros-kinetic-turtlebot 
ros-kinetic-turtlebot-apps 
ros-kinetic-turtlebot-interactions 
ros-kinetic-turtlebot-simulator 
ros-kinetic-kobuki-ftdi 
ros-kinetic-rocon-remocon 
ros-kinetic-rocon-qt-library 
ros-kinetic-ar-track-alvar-msgs
```

Comment: maybe this may be useful ... http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20839/cmd_vel-topic-can-be-manipulated-but-no-messages-are-received/

Comment: I had the same issue and found a video - https://youtu.be/2WBDRbYmE7A This video made sense. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/cmd_vel and /cm_vel_mux are very often interchangeably used where the latter is a multiplexer superimposed to enforce priority in execution. Obviously, if the robot is moving, there has to be a navigation topic with data being published.

You should check the /cmd/vel_mux/input/navi topic - it should be the one that has a Twist message to it and makes the Turtlebot move.

Comment: Yes, I now know that cmd_vel is only a convention and not a requirement, so that helps my understanding a lot.  Seems Turtlebo2 uses cmd_vel_mux and folks on other forums agree that for Turtlebot the topic to use is cmd_vel_mux/input/navi.  The weird thing on my system is I must use cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop to control the robot.  Maybe it is because it is a simulation in Gazebo.  I'm just happy to be able to control it. :)